# Hybris 6.7 system update time

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

We managed to migrate our system into Hybris 6.7.
System update took around 5 hours.

Was this due to the migration, or is this the expected duration after each deployment?
Could this be enhanced by any mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it take once for first upgrade because of type system changes. Did you try and logging it in your pre-prod system? You can check steps elapsed times in logs/screens.